# Find the closest bus stops on the map using Scala spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have a list of locations for the bus stops:

busStopLocations =[(x1,y1),(x2,y2), etc]

I'm trying to find 3 closest locations to my current location(X,Y) using Scala. any suggestions?

Comment: Map the list and calculate the distance to each location. Sort and extract top 3? It would be good to have some example of what you tried so far

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ussed Knn Query in Apache Sedona. more info [here](https://sedona.apache.org/archive/tutorial/sql/?h=knn#knn-query)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).